# what return from read method in pipe()

Tags: c

I have simple question.. when I used read method in pipes, what argument return? Example:

```
temp = read(fb[0],readbuffer,sizeof(readbuffer));
```

what will return to `temp`?

Comment: `man 2 read` has the answer.

Comment: StackOverflow really isn't meant as a replacement for reading the documentation.

Comment: Come on folks. It's the holidays. Let's be jolly. The least we can do is Bing the answer for him: http://linux.die.net/man/2/read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of bytes read from the pipe

Comment: Or `0` on end of file, or negative if there was an error.